# openlayers 3 map doesn't display on bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-bootstrap, openlayers-3

here i'm using this bootstrap [template](http://demo.themewagon.com/preview/first-ever-bootstrap-4-template) in this when i'm trying to add openlayers 3 map it doesn't displaying expect its button . Its will only display when i click on fullscreen mode of openlayers 3. why is this happening  ?

Can anyone have any idea about this.

This is how it display.
[image: This is how it display]

please help !!

Comment: Wow, you didn't inform anything. Please review your question. Think like one of us looking to your question ...

Comment: @JonatasWalker i have edit that template and on that one..... after replacing the stuff added a map as u can see in the screen shot . My main problem is when i load the template its display like that i have shared screen shot . every libraries i have added . Its only display when click fullscreen mode or any other button related to map. So why  this is happening .

Comment: if you doubt me that i missed any libraries  you can download that template . Please try to add on it. Where i'm doing wrong i really don't know